# HTTP Request without touching the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, httprequest

I want to send a HTTP request for the server to save a record from the browser. However I'd like the browser to not have to change pages/reload its content (as many of the solutions I've searched for suggested). Right now I'm using a pop up that performs the action then closing itself, but I'm looking for a better solution. Using rails 4.1.1

Comment: You mean like Ajax? For which there are countless examples.

Comment: Try this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Who is 'I'? Are you developing the website and do you want the visitors' browser to do this automatically for them while they visit your site?  What do you mean by 'save'?